# Ratiometric AD conversion with high excitation voltage

Tags: adc, wheatstone-bridge

Still working on a Wheatstone bridge sensor (a load cell); for reasons unknown it insists to be excited with at least 8V (manufacturer gave no assistance, simply state 10V as nominal excitation)

However most/all (excluding hugely expensive parts) converters have a maximum Vref of 5V, typically *and* I need ratiometric measurement for precision.

So I could use a divider to halve the excitation but then the outputs from the bridge would be out of common mode for the ADC. The only solution I see is to use a (precision) difference amplifier to translate down the signal to mid supply (like 2.5V) and then process it with the ADC. Too bad that with that common range a difference amplifier costs almost like the ADC.

Is there some other trick/magical topology to do the measurement?

I was even thinking to supply the bottom bridge with a negative voltage but then the problem changes to translating the Vref.

Comment: +1 but what I miss are some specific precision requirements (number and conditions), for the following reason: the statement "I need ratiometric" certainly was based on them but whatever additional solution for the common mode will add to the error budget and should be discarded if they make things worse.

Comment: "Still working on a Wheatstone bridge sensor (a load cell); for reasons unknown it insists to be excited with at least 8V (manufacturer gave no assistance, simply state 10V as nominal excitation)"  Sounds to me like this manufacturer that is 'punting' (keeping things simple for themselves by not explaining the full story).  If it is indeed a simple Wheatstone setup, there's no reason not to use a lower excitation voltage, as long as your signal/noise on the output remains acceptable to you.

Comment: If they were simple foil gauges I'd tell the manufacturer he's crazy, I agree with you. However they say they are *semiconductor* gauges so I have no idea of what they need for excitation. In fact *every* appnote I've seen simply uses 5V excitation and put it as a Vref to the ADC